# Replacing doorknob and my current hole is bigger than the new doorknob

Tags: lock

We are replacing our old doorknob with a new Schlage that is keyless.  The current hole in the door is bigger than the new doorknob.  Any suggestions on what we should do to cover the old hole?

Comment: How much bigger? Interior or exterior? Details, please.

Comment: In all my years I have not seen anything bigger than what a keyless would cover unless it is a mortise lock.

Answer (score 1):

Adapter plates are available in various sizes and finishes. Visit a reputable lock & key/locksmith shop or look online. Alternatively, I have used high-performance 2-part wood filler to fill old knob holes, then re-drill to proper size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess since there is no picture to go by but a [mortise lock adapter](https://www.build.com/don-jo-cv-86/s460806?uid=930380&source=gg-gba-pla_930380!c1045779808!a49396355217!dc!ng&gclid=CjwKCAjw7IbaBRBqEiwA6AyZgtymeX8GIkIw8qvs291aZKeH0Ko4KjxMY24aPl7R3fNGixs38XJEghoCaWEQAvD_BwE) my serve you well.

[image]